# getting the value of text field using rspec selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, selenium-webdriver

How do we use selenium webdriver + ruby to check to see if the value of a text field is equal to a certain value?

I was doing:

```
    @tester.browser.find_element(:id => "id_of_text_field").text.should == 'test value'
```

Why doesn't that work?

this test failed ... couldn't get the value of the text field.

Answer (score 1):

Text fields do not have `text`. The value you see in the text field is actually the value of their `value` attribute.

You can get an element's value attribute by doing:

```
element['value']
```

Therefore, your test needs to do:

```
@tester.browser.find_element(:id => "id_of_text_field")['value'].should == 'test value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Write as below using [`should eql(expected)`](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.11/classes/Spec/Matchers.html#M000429)

> Passes if given and expected are of equal value, but not necessarily the same object.

```
# I write in below way, just for readability, you can write it in one line.
elem = @tester.browser.find_element(:id => "id_of_text_field")
elem.text.should eql('test value')
```